# Occasional Crash Setting UILabel Text - NSString substringWithRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have noticed a few crash reports from the App store recently.  However, I can't recreate the error using the simulator or on my iPhone 5.

One of the users emailed me to report the problem and provided some details. The App crashed for this user when they tried to open the view controller which displays a list of recordings. This is is the view controller which failed (BRRecordingsViewController)

The line which failed is where the UILabel text "recordingName.text" is set to a substring of the filename string.

The filename string would typically be something like this:

```
VoCo_DATE_2015-05-14 16:14:55_NAME_Arpeggio #02
```

"Arpeggio #02" is the name of the track. (The text preceding this is a unique identifier and allows tracks to be displayed in order of creation date/time)

The filename will never be empty - it will at least contain the text

```
VoCo_DATE_2015-05-14 16:14:55_NAME_
```

The substring would in this case result in this:

```
Arpeggio #02
```

The track name can be empty. This does not cause the program to fail.

Here is the section of code which is triggering the crash:

```
UILabel *recordingName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
NSRange rangeNameTag = [fileNameWithoutExt rangeOfString:@"_NAME_"];
NSRange rangeOfRecordingName = NSMakeRange(rangeNameTag.location+6, fileNameWithoutExt.length-6-rangeNameTag.location);
recordingName.text = [fileNameWithoutExt substringWithRange: rangeOfRecordingName];
```

Here's the exception I get from the App store crash log.

[image: Last Exception Backtrace]

I cannot recreate the error and therefore can not be entirely sure of the steps leading up to the crash.

By changing the code and forcing bad data into the string I can achieve a crash.

```
*** -[__NSCFConstantString substringWithRange:]: Range {9223372036854775813, 9223372036854775813} out of bounds; string length 10. This will become an exception for apps linked after 10.10 and iOS 8. Warning shown once per app execution
```

Comment: Provide exact details that lead to the crash. What is the full error? What are the exact values involved? Put this info in your question (not in a comment).

Comment: There is no error checking on the ranges!

Comment: You should check that "_NAME_" is present in the `fileNameWithoutExt`. `rangeOfString:` method will return `{NSNotFound, 0}` if the searched string is not found or empty (@""). So, you first check for `rangeNameTag.location != NSNotFOund`.

Comment: More details added @rmaddy

Comment: There are no error check on the ranges @zaph but the filename will always at least contain the text "VoCo_DATE_2015-05-14 16:14:55_NAME_" plus which ever track name was selected.

Comment: @NicolasBuquet - The filename should always begin with "VoCo_DATE_2015-05-14 16:14:55_NAME_" because this is generated when the user makes a recording. They would then assign their own track name which is appended to the filename.  Is it possible that Asian character sets may cause unexpected results with the text string?

Comment: Can they append a zero length track name? Does your code ensure user's track name as a length > 0?

Comment: @rmaddy - Could you explain how to find out the full error from the crash log? I don't believe that it is possible to access the exact values involved when the crash details come from Apple.

Comment: The crash log typically shows an error message before the first stack trace.

Comment: @NicolasBuquet - Yes. I tested in debug / simulator and on my iPhone 5 with a zero length track name.

Comment: If you have user input it should be validated if it is going to be operated on. There is the chance that the user input contains unicode surrogate pairs, emoji and other multi code init characters. In Objective-C string lengths report the number of utf-16 code units not the number of characters and unaware code can end up splitting inside a character. The way to know what the error was is by checking for potential errors and at a minimum logging errors, hopefully recovering from them. Here is one of my test strings: "AB FG"

Comment: @rmaddy I often see error messages in Xcode when I recreate an error. In this case I just have a stack trace for each thread.  The stack frame where the crash occurred is highlighted in orange - 4 [BRRecordingsViewController].  Before this we have [NSString substringWithRange] and before that [NSException initWithCoder]  - Sorry if I've misunderstood - is there somewhere else I should look in Xcode Organiser Crashes?

Comment: @zaph I'm going to test with some of these more unusual character sets.  Do you think it's possible that some character combinations could cause the _NAME_ constant to be (partially) deleted such as a backspace?

Comment: I couldn't achieve any crashes using non-latin characters. However, it occurred to me that if the user left the app recording my accident, it may drain the battery and cause the iPhone to power down before the name "VoCo_DATE_2015-05-14 16:14:55_NAME_" is assigned. I started recording and then powered down the phone to simulate the error and was able to recreate the crash.

Comment: @NicolasBuquet I've applied the change suggested and this caters of the battery fail scenario.